# Unable to connect to a subversion edge server remotely

Tags: windows, svn, windows-firewall, vmware-workstation

I have the following configuration:

1. Windows 7 Enterprise x64 Host running VMWare Workstation v11.0.0 build 2305329
2. Client (VM) is Windows Server 2008 r2 x64
3. Symantec Endpoint Protection client (unmanaged) v12.1.5337.5000
4. using Collabnet Subversion Edge v5.0.1-4144.7

I can connect to subversion's admin port of 3343/4434 from the host computer, however when attempting to connect to the client from two external servers, I get page cannot be displayed. I can connect to the default web port of 80 and get the default IIS 7 page.

I think this may be a firewall configuration situation, however I have tried opening all tcp/udp ports in both windows firewall rules and SEP rules and I still am unable to connect.

I might be able to get it working if I install TFS on port 8080 and uninstall TFS. But I really would rather not.

Comment: For grins and giggles, I disabled SEP on the Host computer and now I can ping the subversion port from a remote server.

Comment: On the host computer, I added a firewall rule that allows all ethernet type 0x800 traffic and now I am able to connect. Will this open a security risk?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Advanced/Profiles section of the firewall rule for "CollabNet Subversion Edge Console". This defaults to Public but you many need Domain and/or Private too.